# MasterDE Personalization Strings

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to map Master Data Extension fields to the available E-Mail Studios' Personalization Strings? If not, is there another easy way to insert Data from MasterDE without a need to query it though AMPscript?

Comment: Hi Michael..did my explanation work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If your master de is sendable, you can use it as your de for that send and won't have to do lookups.

You could also set them as additional profile attributes in email studio and call them as personalisation strings

Comment: I fire an event to another DE where I do send the Email from.

Comment: Then you will have to set them profile attributes

Comment: Agreed - unless you can create filtered DE's based on your master, and use that as the send audience, then there's no other way than to map fields to profile attributes (or simply populate the sendable DE you are firing the event from, with the fields using SQL).